# Making JW 5 player responsive

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, jwplayer

I've been researching ways to make JW player 5 responsive and have tried both CSS/HTML and jQuery examples to modify the video player, but haven't had any success. I'm using WordPress and am trying to add the code to the page using a raw .js module and page-specific css, if that makes a difference.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.360north.org/jwplayer5.9/jwplayer.js"></script>
<video id="mediaplayer" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://state.ak.tvwmedia.net:1935/ktoo-live/_definst_/360north/playlist.m3u8" type="video/mp4"></video>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '640',
    'height': '480',
    'image': 'http://www.360north.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/SmallVideoPlayer1.jpg',
    'modes': [{
        type: "flash",
        src: "http://www.360north.org/jwplayer5.9/player.swf",
        config: {
            file: "360north",
            streamer: "rtmp://state.ak.tvwmedia.net/ktoo-live",
            provider: "rtmp"
        }
    }, {
        type: 'html5',
        config: {
            'file': 'http://state.ak.tvwmedia.net:1935/ktoo-live/_definst_/360north/playlist.m3u8',
            'provider': 'video'
        }
    }]
});
// ]]>
```

Comment: what error or result are you getting?

Comment: Right now, when I embed the video, it only displays at 150px high because the video is not responsive but the website is. I can disable the responsiveness of the embedded video, but then it won't display properly on mobile devices, so I'd really like to make the video itself responsive. I've seen a few examples of this using either jQuery or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This method can be used for the JW Player - http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos

Basically, the iframe method - "Elastic Object & Iframe Embedded Videos"

http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/elastic-videos/

This method works with JW5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to make JWplayer 5 responsive, without an iFrame, but you must add code tags around the embedding code or it won't work: 
http://www.miracletutorials.com/how-to-make-jw-player-5-10-responsive/
I hope this helps?